# Array-to-pointer conversion in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This code can't be compiled with VC++2012.

```
struct Test
{
    int ary1[1];
    int ary2[1];
    void func() {
        int (&ref)[1] = ( true ? ary1 : ary2 );
     }
};

int main() {}
```

The compiler says:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int (&)[1]'
```

Ternary Operator makes Array-to-pointer conversion.

However, GCC never shows this error.
What's the correct behaviour?

Comment: For reference, this code compiles without errors on Apple LLVM version 5.0 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In paragraph 4 of 5.16 [expr.cond] in the standard says:

> If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result
>   is of that type and value category [...]

So the result should be an lvalue to type array of 1 `int` in your case.

Paragraph 5 starts with "Otherwise, the result is a prvalue" which is obviously the other case to the "If..." of paragraph 4.

In my reading paragraph 6 also doesn't apply.

> Lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the second and third operands.

If we've determined that the result is a glvalue then there's no way that the after an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion we have a valid object to use as the result so paragraph 6 *must* be following on the "Otherwise..." started in paragraph 5. To be fair, I don't think that this is completely unambiguous even if an alternative reading to mine would result in greater inconsistency.

tl;dr: I think that gcc is correct in this case.

A workaround could be to use: `*(true ? &ary1 : &ary2)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't determine whether paragraph 6 was applied to this case.